# json-server load all data with one request

Tags: json, json-server

I have a JSON on my local server that has something like this:

```
[ 
  "category1":[
                {..},....
              ],
  "category2":[
                {..},....
              ],
]
```

For the testing purpose I am running Json-server package and running the json server on port 4000.

Obviously I could reach to category1 and category2 by `HTTP://localhost:4000/category1` and `HTTP://localhost:4000/category2`
Is there any way that with **one request** I get the whole JSON back?

at the moment going to `HTTP://localhost:4000/` basically shows the instructions rather than return the whole json

Answer (score 1):

`GET /db` will return the whole json data in the database.

`db.json`:

```json
{
    "category1": [1, 2],
    "category2": [3, 4]
}
```

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:3000/db | jq .
{
  "category1": [
    1,
    2
  ],
  "category2": [
    3,
    4
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can acieve this by adding all the data into another object.
like i did in below example:

```
{
  "main": [
    {
      "category1": [
        {}
      ],
      "category2": [
        {}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

now using this you can get all the data.

```
HTTP://localhost:4000/main
```

i created sample also that you can reffer

code : https://api.npoint.io/b8ecd9041d73761f578f

output  : https://api.npoint.io/b8ecd9041d73761f578f/main

if you have any doubt do comment...

Comment: I know but assume that I do not have access to the JSON server. So I cannot modify it in that way that you think